# how to select value in array with index in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

| id | list |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {759-10,1147-7,931-10} |
| 2 | {719-10,117-2} |

### expected

| id | list1 | list2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 759-10 | 931-10 |
| 2 | 719-10 | 117-2 |

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What is the logic behind this expected result ? What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the first and last elements, use array operations:

```
select id, list[1], list[cardinality(list)]
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f53adb65af6b07bae7f8c6a977181260) is a db<>fiddle.